# IBM Weather REST API 401 Keep getting CORS issues when access

Tags: rest, cors, ibm-cloud, weather-api

I am getting a `40`1 and some cross domain issues when trying to access IBM Weather REST API from either client (browser) or server.

If I generate a URL and try and access it directly from a browser (eg paste it in it works fine and the JSON weather report is returned).

When I try and run the Javascript HTTP request from either the browser or server it seems like it's only allowed to run from an ibm.com domain.

`Failed to load https://twcservice.au-syd.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/-33.00/151.00/forecast/daily/7day.json?units=m&language=en-US: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://*.ibm.com, https://*.ibmcloud.com', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am using the free service on Bluemix. Is this restricted to only run via a Bluemix server? or are there some options I can pass when I create the service on Bluemix

Note, when I make the request I am using the credentials supplied via the Bluemix console. Again, this works via the browser URL bar, but not via code.

Update/More info: if I hit past the URL above into the browser (with creds) it works as above, then if hit it via the web app in the same session it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. So the IBM server is sending the following response header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://*.ibm.com, https://*.ibmcloud.com`

That's an invalid response from IBM. Unfortunately, I think your only option is to complain to IBM, and convince them to

- Return a valid `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header (with only one value)
- Allow people outside of IBM to access it

Without that, I fear you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I did find this separate doucmentation from http://digital.wsi.com/products/v3/developer_map.php?auth=public&country=US&language=en-AU#step1 which is for a different service by the same company (not via IBM Cloud) and it seems like we need to email them to ask for domains to be added. I have also asked IBM for some help

Comment: Cool - update this answer if it works. You could point out that they're currently sending an invalid value, but it might not help your case :)

Comment: Thanks, let me see what they come back with. I was hoping there's some config param somewhether that allows me to change this. This is a custom deployed app on IBM Cloud/Bluemix, opefully they have that option, just could ot find any doco on it.